# GridBagLayout X and y won't go further

Tags: java, gridbaglayout, swingx

Okay, so I'm learning to write and use layouts by hand instead of using the GUI Builder of Netbeans. I know my question may be simple for you but not so simple for someone new to this. My problem is that even if I set gbc.gridx=10 and /or gbc.gridy=2, it won't go further to right. It looks like it's only limiting it to position 1 or 2 but won't go further. Even the gridheight = 2 or any N won't take effect. What am I doing wrong here? Please help. Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
package gridbaglayoutsample;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class GridBagLayoutSample {
JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
JPanel myPanel_1 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
JButton myButton_1 = new JButton("Button 1");
JButton myButton_2 = new JButton("Button 2");
JButton myButton_3 = new JButton("Button 3");

public GridBagLayoutSample(){
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.insets = new Insets(3,3,3,3); //insets are simple spacing for TOP LEFT BOTTOM RIGHT or PADDING

    Border myLineBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.yellow,3);

    myFrame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    myFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    myFrame.setTitle("Grid Bag Layout Sample");
    myFrame.setVisible(true);
    myFrame.pack();
    myFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);


    myPanel_1.setBorder(myLineBorder);

    gbc.gridx = 10; // set x position (STEP 1)
    gbc.gridy = 0; //set y position (STEP 2)
        myPanel_1.add(myButton_1,gbc); // after setting x and y, you can add (STEP 3)
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.gridheight = 2;
        myPanel_1.add(myButton_2,gbc);


    myFrame.add(myPanel_1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GridBagLayoutSample();
}

}
```

Comment: That is correct. you only have two components so therefore the layout only has one column and 2 rows. You can't just randomly place components in a grid that doesn't exist. I don't know what you are attempting to do, so I can't suggest a solution other than to read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for working examples and explanations of the contstraints. Also, the GridBagLayout is one to the more complex to learn, maybe you should be starting with another layout manager first?

Comment: `Even the gridheight = 2 or any N won't take effect.` - if you add a third component, then you could have that component take two rows, then it would be the same height as the two other buttons. Again, look at the tutorial demo, the example there shows how to make a button take a width of 3 columns.